# Apache / Symfony: different PHP settings for given route

Tags: php, apache, symfony, routes, settings

I have a Symfony 3 web application running on a Debian server with Apache 2 and PHP 7.

I am looking for a way to set specific values for the following PHP settings for my admin panel which is served by Symfony via the `/admin` routes.

- file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize
- max_file_uploads

Any idea of how to perform that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you already tried something like `php_value upload_max_filesize ..` in a specific Apache config for those routes?

Comment: I wanted to try that but I don't know how to specify  the route pattern. It would be possible for a whole directory I guess with `<Directory />`. I saw your comment before you edit it and it may work since all my admin controllers are in a common folder, right?

Comment: I think the .user.ini solution won't work, because in Symfony, it is always /web/app.php that gets called (and I think this is what matters, not which file is included). I haven't worked with Apache for some time, so I can't help you with the config. But it should be possible to have `Directory /admin` which shares most config (DocumentRoot to /web, etc), and the only difference being to set a couple of PHP values

Comment: Indeed. But `Directory /admin` won't work since it looks at the physical directory and not the URL. I therefore tried with `LocationMatch "^/admin"` but here I see I cannot use `php_value` in there. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can change php settings using ini_set
[ini_set reference](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php)

You can use this funtion in your controller.

Comment: Doesn't this brings up security issues? I'd rather look for a solution that entails configurating Apache/PHP via the VirtualHost or something like that. Any idea? Thank you

Comment: I don't see any security issue unless you pass user generated data to the functions. If you hardcode the parameters or sanitize the user generated data (a white list of allowed parameters for example) it should be ok.

Comment: I just like to keep configurations out of the application layer. But thanks for the answer, that would work indeed.

Comment: Use parameters and set them in your config.yml then.